# Анимация значения text в SVG

Tags: css3, svg, css-animation, svg-animation, smil

Есть ли в SVG возможность, при помощи тега `animate`, `animateTransform`, `set` или какого-нибудь другого тега, реализовать анимацию смены текста с одного на другой?

Comment: в SVG это сделать сложно но что бы не мучаться придумали экспорт из AI в After Effect , и вот там все эти штуки доступны, к примеру это минимум что показано по этому вопросу : https://codepen.io/airnan/pen/YwroOX

Comment: а какой характер анимации Вас интересует?

Answer (score 3):

Текст в SVG, как любой другой графический элемент имеет координаты `X` и `Y` с помощью которых он позиционируется на холсте svg.

```
    <text x="5" y="75" font-size="60" stroke="yellow" fill="gold">
       Начальный текст Другой текст 
   </text>
```

Изменяя эти координаты с помощью команд анимации `<animate />` `<animateTransform/>` `<set />` `<animateMotion />` можно как угодно анимировать движение текста.

- Горизонтальная анимация текста `<animate  attributeName="x"`
  *Движение текста влево после клика:*

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="450" height="100" style="border:0px solid gray">
  
  <rect x="2" y="12" width="445" height="85" fill="#1A2153"/>
  <text x="5" y="75" font-size="60" stroke="yellow" fill="gold"> Начальный текст Другой текст
     <!-- анимация первой половины фразы  -->
   <!-- Вся фраза  передвигается влево и показывается вторая половина фразы -->
 <animate  attributeName="x" begin="svg1.click" 
         values="5;-435" dur="0.8s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
  </text>
</svg>
```

- Дискретное перемещение текста

Для этого добавляется атрибут `alcMode="discrete"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="450" height="100" style="border:0px solid gray">
  <rect x="2" y="12" width="445" height="85" stroke="gray" fill="none"/>
  <text x="5" y="75" font-size="60"> Начальный текст Другой текст
    <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x" begin="svg1.click" 
         values="5;-435" dur="0.4s" calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"/>
  </text>
</svg>
```

- Замена слов после наведения курсора `begin="gr1.mouseover"` и увода
  курсора `begin="gr1.mouseout"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="450" height="100" style="border:0px solid gray">
  <g id="gr1">  
   <!-- Рамка вокруг текста -->
 <rect id="rect1" x="2" y="12" width="445" height="85"  fill="#1A2153"/>
  <text id="txt1" x="6" y="75" font-size="60" stroke="white" fill="white" pointer-events="none" > Начальный текст Другой текст</text>
  </g>
      <!-- анимация первой половины фразы  -->
   <!-- Вся фраза  передвигается влево и показывается вторая половина фразы -->
    <animate xlink:href="#txt1" attributeName="x" begin="gr1.mouseover"  
         to="-435" dur="0.2s"  calcMode="discrete" fill="freeze"/>
  <!-- Возврат фразы в исходное состояние при отводе курсора -->
  <animate xlink:href="#txt1" attributeName="x"  begin="gr1.mouseout"
         to="5" dur="0.2s" calcMode="discrete" fill="freeze" /> 
  
</svg>
```

- Плавное, построчное движение слов вверх

Используется команда анимации движения вдоль пути

```
<animateMotion path="M 0 0 L 0 -200"  dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
width="400px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 400 40" >
    <rect width="75%" height="100%" fill="#1A2153" />      
   <text
       style="font-size:20px;fill:gold; stroke:yellow; font-family:Garamond"
       x="0"
       y="0">
       <tspan x="20" y="50">Люблю грозу в начале мая,</tspan>
       <tspan x="20" y="100">Когда весенний, первый гром,</tspan>
       <tspan x="20" y="150">Как бы резвяся и играя,</tspan>
       <tspan x="20" y="200">Грохочет в небе голубом.</tspan>
    <animateMotion path="M 0 0 L 0 -200"  dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </text>
</svg>
```

- Движение с остановками на каждой фразе

Для этого используется атрибут:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
width="400px" height="40px" viewBox="0 0 400 40" >
    <rect width="75%" height="100%" fill="#1A2153" />      
   <text
       style="font-size:20px;fill:gold; stroke:yellow; font-family:Garamond"
       x="0"
       y="0">
       <tspan x="20" y="50">Люблю грозу в начале мая,</tspan>
       <tspan x="20" y="100">Когда весенний, первый гром,</tspan>
       <tspan x="20" y="150">Как бы резвяся и играя,</tspan>
       <tspan x="20" y="200">Грохочет в небе голубом.</tspan>
   <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0; 0.075;0.175; 0.325; 0.425; 0.575;0.675;0.825;0.925; 1"
         values="0,0;0,-25;0,-25;0,-75;0,-75;0,-125;0,-125;0,-175;0,-175;0,-204"
         repeatCount="indefinite"       
         dur="8s"
         calcMode="linear">
      </animateMotion>
    </text>
</svg>
```

```
keyTimes="0; 0.075;0.175; 0.325; 0.425; 0.575;0.675;0.825;0.925; 1"
```

Answer (score -1):

Для анимации значения текста использовал requestAnimationFrame